# How many possible combinations for the number of pieces on the board?

Tags: mathematics, pieces

My question concerns the total material available on the chess board (black+white pieces). At the very beginning of a game, there are 2 Kings, 2 Queens, 4 Rooks, 4 Bishops, 4 Knights and 16 pawns. These can be represented by an array (2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 16). As the game progresses, the total amount of material will change, thus the array will change. My question is as follows. Looking at all theoretically possible games played from the initial position, how many unique arrays are possible to reach? The fact that a pawn can be promoted to any light or heavy piece makes the problem even more tricky!

Initial Board

```
16 Pawns
 4 Rooks
 4 Bishops
 4 Knights
 2 Queens
 2 Kings
```

After a pawn capture

```
15 Pawns
 4 Rooks
 4 Bishops
 4 Knights
 2 Queens
 2 Kings
```

Only kings left

```
 0 Pawns
 0 Rooks
 0 Bishops
 0 Knights
 0 Queens
 2 Kings
```

But it get more complex when you include pawn promotion (to any piece excluding pawn and king).

So what is the total number of combinations?

---

I've listed 3 combinations above. Here a 6 more

```
 P  R  N  B  Q  K
32  4  4  4  2  2  Initial Position and remains the same until a capture
32  3  4  4  2  2  First capture frequency combinations.  
32  4  3  4  2  2
32  4  4  3  2  2
32  4  4  4  1  2
31  4  4  4  2  2  Pawn 
etc
etc
0  0  0  0  0  2  Only Kings
```

It get tricky at pawn promotion cos each of the 16 pawns can turn in one of 4 pieces (R B N Q).  Which is why I curious to know the total number of (unique piece frequencies)

Comment: What do you mean by 'combinations'?  The number of different board positions possible with the pieces you specified?

Comment: @TonyEnnis Just the combination of piece frequencies, not board positions.

Comment: Do you distinguish between white and black pieces?

Comment: unclear question, would you be more specific @AdamSpeight ?

Comment: I think you need to write a code for this and then run it and then get an answer :)

Comment: In a legal game, if all pawns have promoted, then some of the other pieces must have been captured. Do you worry about that in your calculation?

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen Yep, so long as it unique. Eg if one position results in 111112 and another has the same it is just one combination of frequencies. Another results in 121112 that be a different combination.

Answer (score 3):

It's :
numberOfPawnsPieces(=17) * numberOfRooksPieces(=5) * numberOfBishopsPieces(=5) * numberOfKnightsPieces(=5) * numberOfQueensPieces(=3) * numberOfKingsPieces(=1)
= 6375

I added one to each number of same piece in case there is no one of its kind(for queens for example, there may be two queens, one queen, or none), except for Kings where there always must be 2 kings on the board, so the number of combinations for kings number is only 1.

**

**EDIT : In cas there is promotions of pawns**

**
My idea to tackle this is to separate all possible cases, i.e. when there is promotion of 1 pawn, promotion of 2 pawns,...,promotion of 8 pawns. ( 8 pawns is the maximum number of possible promotions )
Generally speaking, when `x` pawns are promoted, we will proceed same as above, but the number of pawns will be in each case (16-x), plus an other group of `4 * x` possibly created pieces. Finally we will sum all over the cases :

```
                17*5*5*5*3*1 + SUM[x=1-->16,(16-x+1)*5*5*5*3*(4*x)] = **1 230 375**
```

This is approximate, I may have forgotten some cases, or added some positions that are just impossible to happen in a chess game,...etc.

Comment: This is the correct number if you don't include pawn promotion.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen would you please check my edit for the answer ?

Comment: @Adam Speight check my edit for the answer :)

Comment: Actually there can be 16 promotions: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/shortest-game-with-18-queens, but in a legal game then some of the other pieces must have bee captured on the way. If you only consider legal games, then this becomes a very hard chess question rather than a mathematical question.

Comment: Thanks @DagOskarMadsen for this beautiful game with 16 queens, I thought this was just impossible !

Comment: Your answer now is much too large since you are counting the same piece distributions many times. Your answer would have been correct if promoted pieces were to be considered different from the starting pieces. For instance you are counting two kings and a queen as different from two kings and a promoted queen.

Comment: you're right @DagOskarMadsen, my answer may involve duplicated endgames, I will try to work on this :)

Answer (score 2):

Initialy I posted that only 8 promotions for both sides are posible because pawns are oposed in the same file and to promote one have to be taken.

Edited:

I think that for each promotion one pawn or a piece shoud be taken. Because pawns are in front of each other ,blacks and whites ,to promote one of both have to move to the side(take another piece or pawn) or be taken. then I recalculated the final result to **80094** diferent legal piece combinations. I created this script to show all (i modified thanks to the comments of lodebari)

```
(function (pieceset) {
    'use strict';
    var n = 0,
        cc = function cc(arr) {
            var temparr=arr.slice(0);
            while (temparr[0]>=0) {
                while (temparr[1]>=0) {
                    while (temparr[2]>=0) {
                        while (temparr[3]>=0) {
                            while (temparr[4]>=0) {
                                var maxp = 0;
                                var nump = temparr[1]+temparr[2]+temparr[3]+temparr[4]; 
                                if (temparr[1]>4) maxp+=(temparr[1]-4);
                                if (temparr[2]>4) maxp+=(temparr[2]-4);
                                if (temparr[3]>4) maxp+=(temparr[3]-4);
                                if (temparr[4]>2) maxp+=(temparr[4]-2);
                                nump = nump - maxp;
                                if ((maxp+temparr[0]<=16)&&((nump+temparr[0]+(maxp*2))<=30)) {
                                    n++;
                                    console.log(n,"->",temparr);
                                }
                                temparr[4]=temparr[4]-1;
                            }
                            temparr[4]=arr[4];
                            temparr[3]=temparr[3]-1;
                        }
                        temparr[3]=arr[3];
                        temparr[2]=temparr[2]-1;
                    }
                    temparr[2]=arr[2];
                    temparr[1]=temparr[1]-1;
                }
                temparr[1]=arr[1];
                temparr[0]=temparr[0]-1;
            }
            return 0;
        };
    cc(pieceset);
}([16,20,20,20,18,2]));
```

When you run it it print lines like this:

```
1 '->' [ 16, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2 ]
```

the fist number its the combination number followed by Pawns,Rooks,Knights,Bishops,Queens,Kings. The fist line corresponds the fist position with full board, and the last with the two kings alone.

You can try here : https://repl.it/xlO/4

Comment: Actually, for a pawn to able to promote it is necessary that the pawn in front moves aside (taking a piece or another pawn) or is taken.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the upper limit can not be greater than **2304000**
Which is the answer to the following

```
16 (Pawns) * 20 (Rooks) * 20 (Knights) * 20 (Bishops) * 18 (Queens)
```

But not all of those are possible, so doing a quick programming

```
 c:= 0
 p:= 0 .. 16
 r:= 0 .. 20
 b:= 0 .. 20
 n:= 0 .. 20
 q:= 0 .. 18
 if Sum( p, r, b, n, q, 2) <= 32 then c+=1
```

Calculates **c** to be **305090** combinations. (2<sup>18</sup> < c < 2<sup>19</sup>)

If I just focus on end games (no pawns) I calculate **c** to be **3060**  2<sup>11</sup> < c < 2<sup>12</sup>

Is my algorithm producing the correct results?

Comment: There are some other restrictions. If there are 20 rooks, then there cannot be more than 4 knights, for instance.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen Good point, which suggest the value is lower than these upper bounds.

Comment: Adding the constraint __Sum(r,n,b,a)<= (20-p)__ reduces the combinations to **53068** and **3060**

Comment: The question now says "...all theoretically possible games played from the initial position ....". If you have a large number of promotions, then there must have been several captures on the way. It is going to be very hard to calculate the exact answer, maybe an upper bound is the most we can hope for.

Comment: I think the constraint should be Sum(r,n,b,q)<= (30-p)

Comment: No, it's more subtle than in my previous comment. The constraint is max(r,4)+max(n,4)+max(b,4)+max(q,2)<=(30-p)

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen I suspect that constraint will produce the wrong value. Then can be less than 4 rooks on the board.

Comment: Sure. There are 16 pawns that can promote, so from promotions we get max(r-4,0)+max(n-4,0)+max(b-4,0)+max(q-2,0)<=(16-p). This is equivalent to what I wrote. Trust me, I am a mathematician :)

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen I ain't. So could you explain (like I am 5) how you came that expression.eg  max(q-2,0)? It's possible to have all the 16 pawns promoted to queens and still have the original 2 queen also. Which is 18 queens.  Me Confused. :-(

Comment: If you have 18 queens, then 16 of them must have been promoted. max(q-2,0)=max(16,0)=16. Similarly, max(r-4,0) counts the number of rooks that *must* have been promoted. For instance if there are 6 rooks, then at least max(r-4,0)=max(2,0)=2 of them must have been promoted.

Comment: The formula then counts on the number of pieces on the board that *must* be promoted pieces and compares with the number of missing pawns.

Comment: So I calculate the answers to be **164603** and **32275** (end game). @DagOskarMadsen Thank you for explaining it to me. Less confused :-)

Comment: So for the number of different types of pieces on the board. The number of unique piece frequencies are:-  **1:= 1** , **2:= 94** , **3:= 2168** , **4:= 19296** , **5:= 71628** ,**6:= 91416**

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen Here is a link to a zip containing a csv of all the unique piece frequencies. http://sdrv.ms/1beLLxG

Comment: Impossible. Some of those pawns have to take other things to clear the way for them to be promoted or they need to be taken for promotions to happen.